# ANDROID: Remove 'save' and 'discard' buttons

Tags: android, eclipse, image-processing, android-camera

How can I remove confirmation display ('save' and 'discard' buttons display) after capturing image?

[image]

I want to remove second step without changing application functionality: after `startActivityForResult` function go to `previewCapturedImage()` function.

It's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "OpenCV Demo";
private Uri fileUri;

private ImageView imgPreview;
private Button btnCapturePicture;
private FrameLayout  frameLayout;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this, mOpenCVCallBack))
    {
        Log.e("TEST", "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
private void previewCapturedImage() {
       //TODO something
    }
```

Comment: Does the camera app you show here include the same buttons when it is launched by hand from the home screen?

Comment: Yes, but I don't need these buttons.

Comment: Some camera apps put up those buttons only in the case that they are called using `CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST`. Others display them always. In general there is no reliable way to control whether or not they appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I remove confirmation display ('save' and 'discard' buttons display) after capturing image?

You can't. That is not your app. That is coming from the user's chosen activity for handling `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. That activity is coming from some other developer's app, and that developer is welcome to do whatever that developer wants. If you wish to delegate taking a picture to a third-party app, you will have to live with however that third-party app wishes to take that picture.

Comment: Is it possible to auto accept (choose save button) using a rooted phone version?

Comment: @user8430: Not really, as you have no idea what the "save button" is. There are thousands of device models that ship with hundreds of different default camera apps. Plus, there are hundreds of other camera apps available for installation from the Play Store or elsewhere. The user is welcome to use any of these. None have to even have a "save button", as they could use something else (e.g., gesture) to determine when the user wants to accept a picture. Or, they can automatically "save" the image without giving the user an option.